# ImportError Cannot import name compat in fix_yahoo_finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

In the Anaconda Prompt, Requirement already satisfied:

[image: the Anaconda Prompt]

I follow the Quick Start [from this link](https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/), but received this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name compat fix_yahoo_finance.

I don't understand why.

[image: ImportError Cannot import name compat]

Comment: Do not post images of code.

Comment: The command should be `import fix_yahoo_finance` , seems like you have extra characters in your import statement.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you meant. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @patrick the only thing _I_ see is the `as` statement, which is completely valid and unrelated to this problem

Comment: Yes, that code was not posted at the time and I was irritated by the `compat` in the Error message

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error while using NLTK scripts. I use Anaconda and in my case closing and re-opening Spyder was enough to solve the problem. Regardless of the environment used thus I think that restarting the Python console should solve it.